# Nested "For Each" wont work in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to run a very simple nested 'for each' in VBA; but getting a syntax error. When I delete the line after the second For-Each (PropFromOutput = O.Value) it just works fine. Where am I doing wrong? 
Thank you.

```
Sub CompareAndMark()
Dim Linko As Worksheet
Dim Output As Worksheet
Dim PropFromLinko As String
Dim PropFromOutput As String

For Each L In Linko.Range("B2:B69").Cells
   PropFromLinko = L.Value

   For Each O In Output.Range("A2:A69").Cells
   PropFromOutput = O.Value

   Next O
Next L
End Sub
```

Comment: What error? Saying "I get an error" and then not providing the error is counterproductive.

Comment: Just edited and re-specified the question. Thanks.

Comment: Your update did nothing to clarify the issue. You say you get a "syntax error". *What* is the syntax error?

Comment: The only error message I'm getting is "Compilation error: Syntax error"

Comment: I find that surprising.  I would have expected other errors.  You never set Linko or Output to any object. You should also make it a habit to declare ALL of your variables. You can enforce this with an option in the VBE that will place Option Explicit at the beginning of each module.

Comment: Perhaps you are not showing your full code to us? You didn't Define and `Set` variables but yet call their methods.

Comment: Going through the cells in a range with `For... Each` might not be the best way to go about it. It's cleaner to use a regular `For... Next Loop` by going from the first row to the last row in the selected range. Also, it's not efficient to make so many `Range` based calls to the spreadsheet. Just fetch the whole thing in a single `Variant = Range` operation and then loop through the values. Finally put the results back on the sheet with a `Range = Variant` instruction.

Comment: As long as you make an assignment to your variables `Linko` and `Output`, this code *does* compile and will not raise any errors in Excel 2010 when I test it.

Comment: You should also declare all of your variables as Ron mentions :)

Comment: I'd guess you typed `0.Value` rather than `O.Value`. That would give a plain "syntax error".

Comment: Not sure why you need to nest these in the first place, unless you have provided us with the general case. Nothing in the inner loop depends on the iterator of the outer loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub CompareAndMark()
Dim Linko As Worksheet
Dim Output As Worksheet
Dim PropFromLinko As String
Dim PropFromOutput As String

Set Linko = ActiveSheet
Set Output = ActiveSheet

For Each L In Linko.Range("B2:B69").Cells
   PropFromLinko = L.Value

   For Each O In Output.Range("A2:A69").Cells
   PropFromOutput = O.Value

   Next O
Next L
End Sub
```

This will compile, and run OK (although `L` and `O` values are empty, but I do not know your full code). The reason yours was failing is because you never set the `Worksheet` that `Linko` & `Output` are set to. Please edit the sheets they are assigned to as needed in order to get this to work for you